# How to put validation on form in which button is not used in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three fields start date , end date and , issue tracker group if I select only group then all records of that group should come from issue request table but when I select date then it should display specific date records .
Controller Code -

```
def group_report_list
    @start = params[:date].to_date
    @en = params[:to_date].to_date
    @issue_tracker_group = IssueTrackerGroup.find(params[:id])
    @issue_requests = IssueRequest.where(issue_tracker_group_id: @issue_tracker_group.id,date: @start..@en)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is using normal if..else condition.

```
def group_report_list
    @start = params[:date].to_date unless params[:date].nil?
    @en = params[:to_date].to_date unless params[:to_date].nil?
    @issue_tracker_group = IssueTrackerGroup.find(params[:id])
    unless @start.nil? or @en.nil?
      @issue_requests = IssueRequest.where(issue_tracker_group_id: @issue_tracker_group.id,date: @start..@en)
    else
      @issue_requests = IssueRequest.where(issue_tracker_group_id: @issue_tracker_group.id)
    end
end
```

if you feel this is too lengthy code, you can use the code below

```
def group_report_list
    @start = params[:date]
    @en = params[:to_date]
    @issue_tracker_group = IssueTrackerGroup.find(params[:id])
    condition = "issue_tracker_group_id = #{@issue_tracker_group.id}"
    condition += " AND date BETWEEN '#{@start.to_date}' AND '#{@en.to_date}' " unless @start.nil? or @en.nil?
    @issue_requests = IssueRequest.where(condition)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much , above code worked . Can you please explain how it is working ?

Comment: by default you want the condition with issue_tracker_group_id. so initialized the string with that condition. you need to consider start date and end date only if those dates have chosen. so it will append the 2nd condition only if the dates are present.

Comment: I want to take excel and pdf of the same data but it is showing an error .

Comment: you can use same syntax .. what is the error u r getting ?

Comment: Couldn't find IssueTrackerGroup with 'id'=

Comment: have you checked whether params[:id] is valid and not null ?